# Append Query result data in a table in ajax done function Table will be generated from json data

Tags: php, json, ajax

Here is my query when call a function with `ajax` and return value:

```
$query_product=$this->db->query("SELECT item,item_sku  FROM `item` Where id IN (".implode(',',$res_data).")")->result();

exit(json_encode( array('query_product'=>$query_product)));
```

I want to show the returned value in a modal and in done function:

```
.done(function (res) {

//here i need to do something 

      }
      $('#itemModal').modal('show');
})
```

How can I fetch the value came from the encoded `json` or any other way to return and show the data?

Answer (score 0):

It must be straight forward in your case. Your json encoded string is like:

```
{"query_product":"whatever_it_is"}
```

So you can extract it like this:

```
.done(function(res) {
    var result = res.query_product;
    //any extra manipulation 
 }
```

Comment: How can loop this res.query_product with jquery each and append data in a table ??

Comment: variable 'result' will now contain all the contents of query_product that you sent, so you can loop 'result' with a normal javascript for loop